# After setting up two factor authentication, I get "Repository not found"

Tags: github

After our github has a two factor authentication setup, I can't do pull nor push on command-line due to an error of "repository not found".

```
C:\myproject>git push origin mybranch
Username for 'https://github.com': myname
Password for 'https://myname@github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myproject.git/' not found
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Github is currently having problems... it might be related.
https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: Thanks for the info. The Gitub server should be available right now. I, however, still have the error. It maybe something else?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to that ?

Answer (score 1):

For folks who are facing the same issue,

Enabling 2FA requires us to use the Personal Access Token(PAT) instead of our password. PAT can be generated from Developer Settings tab. While generating the token make sure to give the necessary permissions(scope) like repo read/write access, etc.,

This worked for me.

Comment: I spent many hours trying to figure out why I was still getting the message of repository not found even having done all the steps... GitHub should improve the error messages to save us our precious time...

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your URL.

It should not be `https://github.com/myproject.git/` but `https://github.com/myusername/myproject.git/`

Comment: I will take a look in the regard. I don't change anything locally. If the URL is changed, only possibility is due to the two factor authentication setup. I am able to push after disabling my two factor authentication without any other chagnes.

Comment: @vic Did you create a PAT? (Personal Access Token): https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/. See also : https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#when-youll-be-asked-for-a-personal-access-token-as-a-password

Comment: Yes, I did. And I use my username and personal access token for the login. The error message isn't about access but repository.

Comment: @vic did you find a solution? im running into this now and can't get past it.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I am no longer working in the environment right now.